# How to concatenate a table in select dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, select

Please check below query

```
DECLARE @DBName AS Nvarchar(MAX)
select TOP(1) @DBName=DBName from StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB ORDER BY id DESC
DECLARE @SQL AS Nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL=
'Select TCH.ID,MasterDB.CreatedByUserID,MasterDB.CreatedByDBName,
MasterDB.CreatedByDBName+''.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser'' as waheguru,
( select ISNULL(strFirstName,'''') as firstname from
 dbo.tblSMSecurityUser where UserID=1 ) as waheguru2,MD.DBName,
U.strFirstName,Message,CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),CONVERT(date, 
CH.CreatedDate),6) As CreatedDate,TCH.CreatedDate as CreatedDateTime,
RepliedByUserID,RepliedMasterDBID from 
StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketChatHistory TCH
left join '+@DBName +'.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser U on 
U.UserID=TCH.RepliedByUserID
left join StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB MD on 
MD.ID=TCH.RepliedMasterDBID
LEFT JOIN StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMaster MasterDB on 
MasterDB.ID=TCH.TicketMasterID
where TCH.TicketMasterID=1  and (TCH.IsDeleted <> 1 or TCH.IsDeleted IS 
NULL) order by CreatedDateTime desc'
 PRINT @SQL
 Exec(@SQL)
```

**MasterDB.CreatedByDBName** is the DB name that i want to attach before **dbo.tblSMSecurityUser** in sub-query 
i.e.

```
( select ISNULL(strFirstName,'''') as firstname from
```

dbo.tblSMSecurityUser where UserID=1 ) as waheguru2

i want it to get it as below :

```
( select ISNULL(strFirstName,'''') as firstname from
```

TESTDB.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser where UserID=1 ) as waheguru2

because the Database name is dynamically changed.. is there any way by which i can do it..

Please help me.

Comment: I think that a cursor is your only option here if I understood you correctly and you want to generate queries for multiple databases.

Comment: a cursor is never the only option in t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @DBName AS Nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT TOP(1) @DBName=DBName FROM StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB ORDER BY id DESC
DECLARE @SQL AS Nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL=
'SELECT TCH.ID, MasterDB.CreatedByUserID, MasterDB.CreatedByDBName,
MasterDB.CreatedByDBName.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser as waheguru,
( select ISNULL(strFirstName,'''') as firstname from ' + @DBName + 
'dbo.tblSMSecurityUser where UserID=1 ) as waheguru2, MD.DBName,
U.strFirstName,Message,CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),CONVERT(date, 
CH.CreatedDate),6) As CreatedDate,TCH.CreatedDate as CreatedDateTime,
RepliedByUserID,RepliedMasterDBID from 
StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketChatHistory TCH
left join '+@DBName +'.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser U on 
U.UserID=TCH.RepliedByUserID
left join StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB MD on 
MD.ID=TCH.RepliedMasterDBID
LEFT JOIN StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMaster MasterDB on 
MasterDB.ID=TCH.TicketMasterID
where TCH.TicketMasterID=1  and (TCH.IsDeleted <> 1 or TCH.IsDeleted IS 
NULL) order by CreatedDateTime desc'
PRINT @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood your question  correctly.

```
DECLARE @DBName AS Nvarchar(MAX)
select TOP(1) @DBName=DBName from StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB 
ORDER BY id DESC
DECLARE @SQL AS Nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL=
'Select TCH.ID,MasterDB.CreatedByUserID,MasterDB.CreatedByDBName,
MasterDB.CreatedByDBName+''.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser'' as waheguru,
( select ISNULL(strFirstName,'''') as firstname from
 ' + @DBName + 'dbo.tblSMSecurityUser where UserID=1 ) as 
waheguru2,MD.DBName,
U.strFirstName,Message,CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),CONVERT(date, 
CH.CreatedDate),6) As CreatedDate,TCH.CreatedDate as CreatedDateTime,
RepliedByUserID,RepliedMasterDBID from 
StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketChatHistory TCH
left join '+@DBName +'.dbo.tblSMSecurityUser U on 
U.UserID=TCH.RepliedByUserID
left join StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMasterDB MD on 
MD.ID=TCH.RepliedMasterDBID
LEFT JOIN StreamLeaderMaster.dbo.TicketMaster MasterDB on 
MasterDB.ID=TCH.TicketMasterID
where TCH.TicketMasterID=1  and (TCH.IsDeleted <> 1 or TCH.IsDeleted IS 
NULL) order by CreatedDateTime desc'
 PRINT @SQL
 Exec(@SQL)
```

If the name of the db you want to concat is @dbname then it should work. If not not just change the param and you should be fine.

Hope this helps